# FileExtensionsAttribute and constant Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am having issues with the FileExtensionsAttribute. The validation works just fine and all. But I would like to alter the Extensions property of FileExtensionsAttribute dynamically. The problem is that the property only accepts constant values.

I want to achieve something like:

```
[Required]
[FileExtensionsAttribute(Extensions = MyStringVariable)]
public HttpPostedFileBase Files { get; set; }
```

How can I do this? Is the only way to create a custom attribute for this? It seems that it's not possible to subclass FileExtensions because of the fact that it is sealed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with attributes.  Attributes are immutable in metadata and can't be changed on the fly in this manner.

Comment: Hmm, so it's not even possible with a custom attribute?

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz no. All attributes in .Net are immutable in metadata and hence must have constant values

Comment: Hmm that sucks. Guess I will work out some jquery validation then or something.